# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable when passing arguments to function

Tags: python, django, django-errors

I have a function that does some calculations based on a filtered queryset. I am seeking to pass arguments to the function to inform the filter. The basics:

A view to test the output:

```
def TestPlayerData(request):
    data = PlayerData(1,2)
    print(data)
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

The function called is:

```
def PlayerData(game, player):
    """This is a function based on EventFilterView"""
    opponent = [2]
    qs = Event.objects.filter(g_players=player).filter(g_name__in=game).filter(g_players__in=opponent)
    count_wins = len(qs.filter(g_winner=player))
    count_played = len(qs.filter(g_players=player))
    
    if count_played == 0:
        win_ratio = 'na'
    else:
        win_ratio = count_wins/count_played

    return count_wins, count_played, win_ratio
```

The error received:
"TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

However, if I explicitly name the variables in the function rather than pass them from the view, the function works as expected -- like this:

```
def PlayerData():
    """This is a function based on EventFilterView"""
    game = [1]
    player =2    
    opponent = [2]
    qs = Event.objects.filter(g_players=player).filter(g_name__in=game).filter(g_players__in=opponent)
    count_wins = len(qs.filter(g_winner=player))
    count_played = len(qs.filter(g_players=player))

    if count_played == 0:
        win_ratio = 'na'
    else:
        win_ratio = count_wins/count_played

    return count_wins, count_played, win_ratio
```

I am obviously missing some basic python understanding here and would appreciate a point in the right direction.

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: You are passing a single integer (`1`) for your `game` argument, then try to use it as if it were a list (`.filter(g_name__in=game)`). Try `.filter(g_name=game)`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the first block of code, you pass `data = PlayerData(1,2)`

`PlayerData()` however eventually uses `.filter()` on the parameters which you cant do on int, which would raise a TypeError.

In your final example where you write in your own #'s after the fact, you pass in game as a list, where in the first block of code game was an int. You're passing it in correctly when you do it manually.